# member initializer lists in constructor with same-name variables

Tags: c++, c++11, member-initialization

In this example:

```
class foo{
    public::
        foo(int x):x(x){
        }
        int x;
    };
```

My compiler is able to understand that, in `x(x)`, the inner `x` is the argument and the outer `x` is the member variable without writing `this->`.

Is this behaviour a standard one?

Comment: Yes.  I find it confusing though, and try to name the argument and member variable distinctly (for example, trailing underscore).  Comment not answer because I can't find the chapter and verse (and I'm surprised this isn't a duplicate).

Comment: ... and oh look, @LogicStuff has found the duplicate.

Comment: [Wasn't that hard.](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B%20member%20initializer%20list%20same%20name&rct=j)